# ImageView doesn't refresh

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have n bitmaps On my SD card (using emulator) numerated like: "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", ...

I want load them in my ImageView in rapid succession, from "1.jpg" to "xy.jpg", like a short video.

**But, after a short delay it will show only THE LAST bitmap saved in my directory!**

Basically, when I click the "Replay" button in my ImageView:

```
public void replay(View view) {
    new replayAsync().execute();
}
```

This asynctask will execute:

```
class replayAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    File temp = null; // This will be the path of the last directory created

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int i;

        // Searching for the last created directory for my replay,
        // starting from Directory number 10 (newer, if it exists)
        // to 0 (older)

        for (i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            temp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Android/data/"
                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                    + "/Files/"
                    + i);
            if (!temp.exists())
            {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("last path created is: " + temp);
                break;
            }
        }


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                    String path = temp + File.separator + c + ".jpg";
                    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
                    try {
                        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        imgView.invalidate();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Error!");
                    }
                 }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, I've tried with invalidate, postinvalidate, without runOnUiThread, without AsyncTask, but nothing...

What could it be?

Comment: drawing is done on the ui thread, which means that no drawing is done until the method you run on the ui thread is completed. meaning no drawing is done until the last image is set. consider using an animation object instead.

Comment: Shouldn't this `"/Files/" + i` be `"/Files/"+ i + ".jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a for loop to move from one image to other, even if the images change, you won't be able to see the change because it happens so quickly. The idea will be to wait for some time before you move to the next image. You can use the timer class to provide some delay before the next image is displayed.

Comment: Forgot to mention: yeah, i tried with Thread.sleep(1000) too, nothing changed